# Controller computed property is not showing new data additions immediately, where the data is not those returned from the route model

Tags: ember.js

Summary:

Controller computed property issue: In one case, I can see all the things getting added but not see the newly added things immediately ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/395)), and in another case I can see the newly added things immediately but the previously added things don't show up ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/404)).

*Second Update of Aug 26:*

So I was thinking ... I have these two complementary pieces of code. I just need to combine them and achieve perfection, right? Sadly, it failed miserably, as you [can see in this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/419/edit), nothing shows up at all. :(

This is my *failed* attempt to combine the two RecordArrays:

```
officelist: function(){
  var allrecords = [];
  console.log("in oficelist");

  // get the record array that shows previously added records
  var a_recordarray =  App.Office.find({org_id: 'myorgid'});
  a_recordarray.forEach(function(record){
    allrecords.push(record);
  });
  console.log(a_recordarray.toString());
  console.log(allrecords.length);

  // get the record array that shows newly added records
  var b_recordarray = App.Office.filter(function(office) {
        return office.get('org_id') === 'myorgid';
    });
  b_recordarray.forEach(function(record){
    allrecords.push(record);
  });
  console.log(b_recordarray.toString());
  console.log(allrecords.length);

  // return the combination
  return allrecords;

}.property('content.@each')
```

---

Details:

I have this [simple jsbin app](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/395) that uses a controller computed property in the code to show a list of names to be displayed. The problem is that whenever a new name is added, you have to refresh the page to see it getting displayed.

You can see its [code here](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/395/edit).

Controller code with computed property:

```
officelist: function(){
  return App.Office.find({org_id: 'myorgid'});
}.property('content.@each')
```

Route returning a different model:

```
App.OrganizationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Org.find();
  }
});
```

Handlebars:

```
{{#each officelist}}
  <li>{{officename}} </li>
{{/each}}
```

Constraints: I do need to have the 'org_id' present and I do need to have the route model returning a different model from the model that is displayed.

*Update Aug 26:* Jonathan [has made some progress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18436421/733034) but please see my comment to his answer as it doesn't solve the problem completely.

*Updated Aug 24: Added the complexity that the data to be displayed is different from those returned in the router model. (Also changed ArrayController to ObjectController, but this change has no consequences as ObjectController also has the `content` property.), below is the old stuff:*

<strike>Controller code with computed property:</strike>

```
officelist: function(){
  return App.Office.find({org_id: 'myorgid'});
}.property('office.@each')
```

Handlebars:

```
{{#each officelist}}
  <li>{{officename}} </li>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the computed property is cached and will only refresh when `office.@each` changes. The `office` property is not defined on that controller, so `office.@each` is always null. Probably what you want instead is `content.@each`. So:

```
officelist: function(){
  return App.Office.find({org_id: 'myorgid'});
}.property('content.@each')
```

Now the page will refresh whenever a new office is added.

Comment: Mike, as always, I am so amazed and grateful by your prompt and working answers! [fixed jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/385). Can you explain where `content` comes from?

Comment: Happy to help. Every ArrayController has a content property. By default, Ember.Route's `setupController` will set that content property to whatever is returned by the model hook. So since `App.OrganizationRoute` has a model hook that returns `App.Office.find()`, `content` is a live collection that includes all organizations.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the explaination! My jsbin case was too simple, I have updated the question with a [new jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/395/edit)

Comment: Worst comes to worst, there is a semi-acceptable solution based on this answer. I can just manually refresh the page every time the "add" button is clicked with `location.reload()`. [See the code in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/421/edit) and [see it in action](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/421/).

Comment: I've got a version that works without the refresh. Had to refactor a bit. Not sure all the changes I made were needed, but have a look: http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/427/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Change App.OrganizationController's officelist property to this:

```
officelist: function() {
  return App.Office.filter(function(office) {
    return office.get('org_id') === 'myorgid';
  });
}.property()
```

The reason is that calling `App.Office.find()` tries to fetch from the adapter, in your case, localStorage. What you want to do instead is simply pull it out of the store. For this, `App.Office.filter()` (and in other cases, `App.Office.all()`) is your friend.

**Update:**

To also fetch other offices previously saved, fetch them using find(). A place you might do this is when the controller gets initialized in the route's `setupController` hook.

```
App.OrganizationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Org.find();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    App.Office.find({org_id: 'myorgid'});
  }
});
```

You don't need to worry about storing the result because any resulting Office records will be loaded into the store, and your `App.Office.all()` and `App.Office.filter()` calls will get the updates automatically.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, your answer doesn't completely work. Sure, it adds the new entries immediately, but after you refresh the page, you don't see the previous entries. [See it in the jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/404), and compare to the [jsbin in the answer](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/395) where it shows the previous entries after refreshes but doesn't show new entries immediately. If there is only a way to combine the best of both!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't do the `find` call with the `org_id` parameter everything works as you want:

```
officelist: function(){
  return App.Office.find();
}.property('content.@each')
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/407/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Hi flynfish: "Constraints: I do need to have the 'org_id' present". In my real app, the constraint is not something trivial like org_id, so this question is just an example.

Comment: Gotcha, wasn't sure if that was in reference to having it in the `find` call.

Comment: Saved my life. Thanks :)